# What can I call 2nd and 3rd place finishes in a competition?

Tags: meaning, phrases, terminology, word-usage

There are many awards I received from the sport I did. I thought to compress everything and write as 'Inter university and All island winner' but I have placed only 2nd and 3rd places. What is the best way to correct this?

Comment: I assume that you mean *"I was second in the Inter-University competition and third in the All-Island competition"*.

Answer (score 7):

A concise way to put it would be **placegetter** or **placed**. In the UK, Australia and New Zealand, "placed" would be understood to be in the top three. My understanding is a place in the US means first or second.

**Medallist**/**medalled** (UK spelling) or **medalist**/**medaled** (US spelling) might work if a medal was awarded.

One more possibility is **podium finish** - the first three in a motor sport event or cycling.

Comment: In horse betting, yes. "A win bet means your horse must win, a place bet means it must finish first or second and a show bet means it must be first, second or third though of course this means a lower payout." Dunno about other contexts.

Comment: +1. But you'd want to be very clear about what you mean if you say you "medaled" in some high-stakes event.

Comment: Yes to what @tchrist said: In the U.S., "place" and "show" without other qualifiers are usual only in horse-racing AFAIK. On the other hand, it's not uncommon to say that you "placed fifth", for example, in any kind of competition.

Answer (score 1):

Even if metal discs weren't actually handed out, I'd have thought people would understand if you said silver and bronze.

Answer (score 0):

"Place getter" means achieving first, second or third place, though that is a relatively informal term. Depending on the context, it might be better to use the verb "placed"; something like:

> Placed in inter-university and all-island competitions

If medals are awarded in these competitions, "medalist" would be even better:

> Medalist in inter-university and all-island competitions

The phrase "runners up" is close, but is used to denote multiple competitors in a single competition who placed immediately after the winner. If you use "runner up" in the context of multiple events, it would be assume you were the single runner up (i.e. placed second) in each event.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

first runner-up, second runner-up

Answer (score 0):

One option is "winner's circle," defined by [Dictionary.com Unabridged](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/winner-s-circle) as follows:

> any select group of winners, achievers, or those that have been accepted as worthy:
>
> *the winner's circle of fine wines.*